# Is there any function which can delete specific string in each row in the file by using python

Tags: python

I am new to python and try to use write the excel data into a text file with a specific format. But somehow I am facing a problem with duplication of data.

```
f = open("test1.txt", "a+")                                                                   # Text 
file create here

f5 = []
i = []
j = []
flag = False
for sheet in allSheetNames:
     currentSheet = theFile[sheet]


     for row in range(2, currentSheet.max_row + 1):                                          
    
    
        for column in "ABCDEF":                                                              
            cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
        
        
            if currentSheet[cell_name].value == None: 
                j = I
                flag = True
            else:
                f.write("{}\t".format(currentSheet[cell_name].value))
                i = cell_name
                flag = True
            

                #if flag == True:
                   #if j != I:
                      # print("{}\t".format(currentSheet[i].value))
             
                     #flag = False
    
f.close()                                                                                 
 exit()
```

The committed part actually I am trying to compare the column number and similar column number is trying to avoid `enter code here duplication.

Here is the text file which actually I required as an output.
enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqOyV.png)

Comment: Don't include pictures of text in your question, include the text and format appropriately. It's unclear what your problem is exactly. Are you getting something else written to the file from what you expect? If so, please provide an example of the text you do get in the file as well, so we can see the difference with what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for commenting I will do update the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, This is solved by using separate indexes first and elemental those indexes which are duplicate.